# Can't see my service in administrative tools -> Services

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a service I have developed myself in C# and it includes an msi installation package. When I install this on my own computer I can see it (and start/stop it) in administrative tools -> Services but on another (very similar) machine I can't. I don't really care that much about whether I can see it there but somehow I'd like to be able to start/stop the service. Is there any other way to do that than thru administrative tools -> Services?

Of course, also an answer to "why doesn't the service appear in administrative tools -> Services" would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 4):

I don't remember seeing any machine with a functional service that did not appear in the Services window. My first guess would be that your service is, in fact, **not installed**.

Try installing it again [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984379(VS.71).aspx)] with

```
installutil yourproject.exe
```

If it's not already in your PATH, look for *installutil* in    %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ (or whatever .NET version you've got in there).

Answer (score 0):

Does this other machine have the appropriate version of .Net installed ?